# One who lives in the same city in relation to another person

Tags: société, demande-de-mot

I have [asked](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19722/one-who-lives-in-the-same-city-in-relation-to-another-person) this question on [*English Language Learners*](http://ell.stackexchange.com) and I would like to know the French version too.

I found in [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/concitoyen/17936?q=concitoyen#17810) the term “*concitoyen(ne)*” which is applicable for both city and country.

I would like to know if we can make a difference when we refer to a city compared to a country and if there are supplementary terms to express this meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut exprimer cette relation par le nom des habitants de la ville, ou du département :

> Nous sommes tous les deux parisiens (habitants de Paris) ou, varois (habitants du
>   département du Var) depuis de longues années.

En province, on dira plutôt :

> Nous sommes du même pays !

et plus familièrement

> On est du même pays !

Nous habitons des villages, des bourgs, voire des lieux-dits, dans les limites des ancienne régions : par exemple l'Aunis ou la Saintonge.

Ici *pays* n'a rien à voir avec *country*, mais plutôt avec *paysage*, c'est-à-dire une zone géographique qui offre un type de paysage homogène, souvent rattaché à un bassin fluvial, à une vallée de montagne ou à une zone géologique.

Answer (score 1):

"Concitadin" is the word you are looking for. However it is (extremely) rarely used, and I have not found much dictionnaries with this entry.

Comment: Concitadin est *vraiment* mal sonnant, le correcteur automatique ne le connaît pas, pour http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/concitadin il n'existe pas non plus. Comme ce mot est méconnu, l'oreille 'normale' ajoutera un *de* devant citadin. Il semble perdurer en espagnol, mais s'il était usuel au XVIe siècle, il est tombé en désuétude. On peut le connaître, car compréhensible en rapprochement de *concitoyen*. Ne pas l'utiliser dans l'hexagone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "compatriote", which also has the dual meaning. However, my personal experience is that it is used more for people of the same country ("patrie").